# Copying one 2d array to another by swapping pointers in C

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, multidimensional-array, copy

How can one copy a `unsigned char array1[5][5]` to another `unsigned char array2[5][5]` by swapping pointers?

Comment: Please describe what do you mean with "by using pointers".

Comment: Usually copy elements of array1 to array2 done in `for loop` or `c` library function `memcpy'.

Comment: `double array_one[] = {1,2,3};
double array_two[] = {9,8,7};

double *left = array_one;
double *right = array_two;

double * swap = left;
left = right;
right = swap;`
Instead of changing the elements, changing the pointers between the named arrays @Uduru

Comment: @pvc I am currently using memcpy but I've been told that swapping pointers is much more time efficient

Comment: If there is a need to transfer content from one contiguous memory block to the another (i.e. from one array to another) then memcpy() is probably faster than any looping algorithm.  BTW, the first argument to `memcpy()` ***is*** a pointer, so there  is that.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways.

The simplest way is to use the standard string function `memcpy`. For example

```
#include <string.h>

//...

memcpy( array2, array1, 5 * 5 * sizeof( unsigned char ) ); 

// or as `sizeof( unsigned char )` is always equal to 1 then

memcpy( array2, array1, 5 * 5 );
```

The same result can be achieved by using for loops like

```
for ( unsigned char ( *p1 )[5] = array1, ( *p2 )[5] = array2; 
      p1 != arra1 + 5; ++p1, ++p2 )
{
    for ( unsigned char *q1 = *p1, *q2 = *p2; q1 != *p1 + 5; ++q1, ++q2 )
    {
        *q2 = *q1;
    }
}
```

Or you can reinterpret the two-dimensional arrays as one-dimensional arrays like

```
for ( unsigned char *p1 = ( unsigned char * )array1, *p2 = ( unsigned char * )array2;
      p1 != ( unsigned char * )array1 + 5 * 5 * sizeof( unsigned char );
      ++p1, ++p2 )
{
    *p2 = *p1;
}
```

Comment: @ryyker It is a function that is declared in the header <string.h> The header is identified as a header for string handling. The corresponding section is named like "7.23 String handling <string.h>"

Comment: It's quite crazy that the second and the third solutions are taking more time than memcpy for a unsigned char array1[950][950] haha. 
Thanks a lot for the reply! @Vlad from Moscow